# ¿Como se elimina un valor null?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
def aperturaCsv():
      arch ='h.csv'
      df = pd.read_csv(arch, sep=',')
      #df = df.replace({"-9999": NaN, "-9999.0": NaN})
      df = df.dropna()
      return df
```

Estoy trabajando con python (libreria pandas), tengo un dataframe con valores nulos representados con -9999, necesito eliminar todas las columnas que sean nulas, o sea, que todo el contenido de la columna sea -9999, trate con la funcion dropna y no me funciona, adjunto mi codigo y como me lo muestra

de ante mano muchas gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Coloca el codigo en texto para que sea facil ayudar.

Comment: Soy un poco nueva, no se bien como, pero creo que ahi lo puse, muchas gracias

Comment: Pero por lo que veo todas las columnas tiene -9999.0 por lo que te vas a quedar sin datos, si eliminas cada columna que tenga el -9999.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero vamos a crear un ejemplo mínimo verificable de tu `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
df_limpiar = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1.,2.,3.,-9999.,1.,5.,-9999.,-9999.],
              "col2":[6.,-9999.,2.,4.,-9999.,3.,5.,6.],
              "col3":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
             })

print(df_limpiar)
```

**Salida:**

```
   col1     col2    col3
0   1.0     6.0     1
1   2.0     -9999.0 2
2   3.0     2.0     3
3   -9999.0 4.0     4
4   1.0     -9999.0 5
5   5.0     3.0     6
6   -9999.0 5.0     7
7   -9999.0 6.0     8
```

Hay varias formas, yo creo que la más sencilla cuando empiezas con `Pandas` es buscar el número y convertirlo a `NaN` para borrarlo con el método `.dropna()`

```
df_limpiar = df_limpiar[df_limpiar != -9999].dropna(axis=1)
print(df_limpiar)
```

**Salida:**

```
    col3
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   6
6   7
7   8
```

**Explicación**

1. `df_limpiar[df_limpiar != -9999]`: busca y transforma todos los números que sean -9999 en `NaN`.
2. `.dropna(axis=1)`: veo que ya lo has usado, borra todos las columnas que contienen `NaN` cuando el `axis=1`. Si quieres borrar por filas utiliza `axis=0`.

Todo esto puedes verlo en la documentación oficial de pandas:

- Buscar datos mediante [slicing e indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)
- El método [`.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

#### Extra

- En inglés `axis` significa eje. En matemáticas en las matrices se utiliza el `0` para representar las filas y el `1` para indicar las columnas.

Comment: muchas gracias!!!!, me sirvio