# Eliminar filas de un excel con pyhton

Tags: python, pandas

Mi programa en python hace documentos de csv con datos de unos usuarios, pero me sugieren que elimine aquellas ***filas*** que no tengan contestada la columna "Telefono" es decir que esten en blanco.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el caso de la imagen deberian eliminarse los ultimas dos filas porque no tienen el telefono. Creo que se puede hacer con pandas.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df[(df[['Nombre','Apellido','Pais','Telefono']]  == "")]
df.to_csv('SALIDA.csv', index=None)
```

Intnente eso pero me borro todo el contenido y solo me dejo el nombre de las columnas. Ojala puedan ayudarme.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como se elimina un valor null?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/420130/como-se-elimina-un-valor-null)

Comment: Hola, Si funciona pero ya me he dado cuenta y existen otras columnas en blanco que si se deben de quedar. Solo quiero eliminar las filas que no tengan contestado "Telefono" :s

Comment: Analizá bien aquella respuesta, y adaptala según sea tu caso. En especial, prestale más atención al paso 1 de la explicación.

Comment: @padaleiana la respuesta es buena, pero no todo va por el mismo camino

Comment: Si funciona lo que dice @padaleiana pero quiza me falta mas experiencia o como que no se acopla bien a lo que busco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La vida con pandas es muy fácil. Antes de *exportar* tu DataFrame utiliza el método `drop` al cual le pasaremos los índices a borrar, estos índices son obtenidos mediante un *filtro*.

```py
#replicamos tu dataframe
cols = ["nombre", "pais","telefono"]
data = [
        ["siro","mexico","3824682"],
        ["christian", "osaka", ""]
        ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

#obtenemos los indices a borrar
condicion = df[df['telefono'].isna()].index
#borramos
df.drop(condicion , inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hola Christian, he preguntado a mi supervisor y lo que pasa es que existen otras columnas en blanco que si se deben de quedar. Solo quiero eliminar las filas que no tengan contestado "Telefono"

Comment: @Siro27 he editado la respuesta

Comment: Ya lo aplique a mi codigo y no borra nada :s

Comment: @Siro27 era lo que me temía, he editado la respuesta

Comment: Exactamente eso buscaba! Otra ves muchas gracias @Christian